# API Gateway -> Lambda -> DynamoDB using Cognito. HTTP POST-> Unable to read response but returns a code 200

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, amazon-cognito

**Scenario**:
I query an HTTP POST (using Authorizer as Header parameter from Cognito).
When I try to fetch/read the query response, it triggers the error event. However, in the browser, I can see how 2 HTTP POST responses with 200 code and one of them returning the valid response. For example: if I make the request via POST man I receive the data in 1 response in a good way.

**Problem**:
I am unable to print the result because it launches the error event with not valid response data.

**Browser images**:
https://i.postimg.cc/MTMsxZjw/Screenshot-1.png
https://i.postimg.cc/3RstwMgv/Screenshot-2.png

**Lambda code**:

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 

exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback){
    var params = {
        TableName : "data-table"
    };
    documentClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.Items));
            callback(null, data.Items);
        }
    });
}
```

**Client side JS code**:

```
function requestData(pickupLocation) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: _config.api.invokeUrl,
        headers: {
            Authorization: authToken,
        },
        data: "{}",
        cache: false,
        success: completeRequest,
        error: errorRequest
    });
}

function completeRequest(response) {
    alert("hello");
    alert(response.d);
}

function errorRequest(response) {
    alert("hello1");
    alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
}
```

Comment: Could please you share the response details not in picture format?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://***.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/recurso' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://***.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/recurso with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/*** for more details

Comment: This looks like your API gateway has CORS disabled. I know you mentioned it is enabled, but can you try enable it again and leave it to default values, and then do "deploy API" and see if it works?

Comment: Excellent! It solves the problem. But it was a trick. When you enable CORS you have to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin* (it is hidden in advance options)

Comment: Good to hear, I added the comment as an answer so you can mark this as solved then (using the checkmark option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to further clarification based on the comments, this looks like API gateway has CORS disabled or enabled with incorrect header value returns.

The solution is to re-enable CORS through API gateway and in the advanced options add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the header response (if not already on by default).

Answer (score 0):

If you're proxying the response, you need to follow a specific format as [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

```js
    'use strict';
console.log('Loading hello world function');
 
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let name = "you";
    let city = 'World';
    let time = 'day';
    let day = '';
    let responseCode = 200;
    console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));
    
    // This is a simple illustration of app-specific logic to return the response. 
    // Although only 'event.queryStringParameters' are used here, other request data, 
    // such as 'event.headers', 'event.pathParameters', 'event.body', 'event.stageVariables', 
    // and 'event.requestContext' can be used to determine what response to return. 
    //
    if (event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters.name) {
        console.log("Received name: " + event.queryStringParameters.name);
        name = event.queryStringParameters.name;
    }
    
    if (event.pathParameters && event.pathParameters.proxy) {
        console.log("Received proxy: " + event.pathParameters.proxy);
        city = event.pathParameters.proxy;
    }
    
    if (event.headers && event.headers['day']) {
        console.log("Received day: " + event.headers.day);
        day = event.headers.day;
    }
    
    if (event.body) {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        if (body.time) 
            time = body.time;
    }
 
    let greeting = `Good ${time}, ${name} of ${city}. `;
    if (day) greeting += `Happy ${day}!`;

    let responseBody = {
        message: greeting,
        input: event
    };
    
    // The output from a Lambda proxy integration must be 
    // of the following JSON object. The 'headers' property 
    // is for custom response headers in addition to standard 
    // ones. The 'body' property  must be a JSON string. For 
    // base64-encoded payload, you must also set the 'isBase64Encoded'
    // property to 'true'.
    let response = {
        statusCode: responseCode,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
    };
    console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
    return response;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by proxy the response? I just query the lambda function using the Auth token got from Cognito

Comment: They mean if you have API gateway acting as a proxy to your Lambda (which it looks like that's what you have setup) you should return a response in the correct format. So from your end, all you have to change is instead of callback(null, data.Items);, do callback(null, response) and use the response format above

Comment: It does not work. let response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data.Items)
    };
    console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      callback(null, response);                                                                                Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
  "body": "[{\"tap\":\"001\",\"id\":\"1\"}]"
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome you probably need the [cors plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) .

Comment: I can not design a solution based on a extension. Thanks anyway for your response

Comment: you can enable it throught an api-gateway also , if you are using one.

Comment: It is enabled in API gateway

Comment: I dont know anything except the plugin sorry.